# Delete all files that don't start with a certain string in a folder

Tags: macos, unix

How can I delete all files that don't start with "2012" in a particular folder?

This is on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` to select all files (`type f`) that don't (`!`) start with 2012 (`"2012*"`). You then `rm` (remove) them right away, or let the `delete` switch do that for you.

```
find . -type f ! -name "2012*"
```

Note that this recursively descends into subdirectories. If you want to be sure that you don't remove stuff you actually want to keep, make sure to use the right options (so check out `man find` for more).

For example, `-maxdepth 1` will not go into subdirectories.

Now, remove those files:

```
find . -type f ! -name "2012*" -delete
```

Comment: Or  `find . -type f ! -name "2012*" -delete`. Implies `-depth`, but that doesn't make a difference for file matches only.

Comment: For some reason I thought `-delete` was GNU-only. Changed that, it's safer anyway.

Comment: I had to double-checked as well. BSD/GNU differences confuse me every time.

Comment: Or instead of `-delete` you could pipe into `rm`.

Comment: @ScottWilson No, the whole point of `delete` is to be efficient and secure. You could use `-exec rm`, which is *somewhat* safe, but as a general rule: If you're *piping* `find` output into something else, you're doing something wrong (the command is unsafe by default, and probably not portable). Please read [Finding Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files).